# How to download Python modules on VS Code

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm kinds new in the world of programming and ever since I started learning I got really comfortable working with VS Code due to its environment which is very flexible.

I'm in the process of doing Harvard's CS50 course and I need to download different modules for my code to work. For example I need Pygame for the Minesweeper project. I did download Pygame snippets from the extension tab. However when I try to run the code, it says "No module named 'Pygame'"

I'm also doing the Machine Learning with Python course on Sololearn, which requires Sk-learn.

I also tried using the "pip install" for both but I get the following error:
{
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- pip install pygame
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

}

I tried everything that I knew but still I couldn't pass this obstacle.

If someone could help me with this, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: have you tried "python -m pip install pygame"?

Comment: Yeah, I did try executing it in the terminal, but nothing. I did get Anaconda, and I can say with out a doubt that it was a lifesaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution), especially for Machine Learning. I've been using it in combination with VS Code for quite some time and it works really good.

Once you have installed Anaconda, you can then create Conda environments where you can use `pip install` and `conda install`. For more information about that, I suggest that you get familiar with Anaconda and check out some tutorials on how to use and install `Anaconda`.

Comment: Thanks, Anaconda is way better, and I never thought that it would be this easy and simple. Again, thanks alot